# AYUDA CON CONDICIONALES (IF ELSE)

Tags: javascript

Estoy aprendiendo JS online y me piden hacer un programa donde se realice lo siguiente:

1. Hacer al menos cinco preguntas
2. Mantener un registro de la cantidad de preguntas que el usuario respondió correctamente
3. Proporcione un mensaje final después de la prueba para que el usuario conozca la cantidad de preguntas que respondió correctamente.
4. Clasifica al jugador. Si el jugador respondió a las cinco correctamente, dele la corona de oro a ese jugador: 3-4 es una corona de plata; 1-2 respuestas correctas es una corona de bronce y 0 correctas es ninguna corona.

Por alguna extraña razón la cual todavía no identifico, solo consigo tener 2 respuestas correcta. ¿Por que no se sigue sumando a la variable de respuestas correctas? ¿Qué necesito modificar?

```
var question1 = prompt("2 + 2 = ?");
var userAnswer1 = parseInt(question1);

var question2 = prompt("Capital de Morelos");
var userAnswer2 = question2.toUpperCase;

var question3 = prompt("Primer dia de la semana");
var userAnswer3 = question3.toUpperCase;

var question4 = prompt("Cuanto vale PI");
var userAnswer4 = parseInt(question4);

var question5 = prompt("8 * 3 = ?");
var userAnswer5 = parseInt(question5);

var userAnswerCorrect = 0;

if( userAnswer1 === 4) {
  userAnswerCorrect ++;
}

if( userAnswer2 === "CUERNAVACA" || userAnswer2 === "CUERNA") {
  userAnswerCorrect ++;
}

if( userAnswer3 === "LUNES") {
  userAnswerCorrect ++;
}

if( userAnswer4 === 3.14 || userAnswer4 === 3.1416) {
  userAnswerCorrect ++;
}

if( userAnswer5 === 24 ) {
  userAnswerCorrect ++;
}

document.write("<p>You got " + userAnswerCorrect + " answers correct!");

if( userAnswerCorrect === 5) {
  document.write("<p>You got a GOLD CROWN!</p>");
} else if( userAnswerCorrect === 4 || userAnswerCorrect === 3 ) {
  document.write("<p>You got a SILVER CROWN!</p>");
} else {
  document.write("<p>You got a BRONZE CROWN!</p>");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema está en tus respuestas 2 y 3. Estás tratando de pasarlas a mayúsculas pero no están realmente llamando al método:

```
var question2 = prompt("Capital de Morelos");
var userAnswer2 = question2.toUpperCase;

var question3 = prompt("Primer dia de la semana");
var userAnswer3 = question3.toUpperCase;
```

Lo correcto debería ser:

```
var question2 = prompt("Capital de Morelos");
var userAnswer2 = question2.toUpperCase();

var question3 = prompt("Primer dia de la semana");
var userAnswer3 = question3.toUpperCase();
```

Observa cómo llamo al método `toUpperCase()` usando los paréntesis. Es por eso que al comparar no te daba el resultado esperado:

```
> var respuesta = prompt("Nombre: ");
> respuesta
"César"
> respuesta.toUpperCase
ƒ toUpperCase() { [native code] }
> respuesta.toUpperCase == "CÉSAR"
false
> respuesta.toUpperCase()
"CÉSAR"
> respuesta.toUpperCase() == "CÉSAR"
true
```

El segundo error es que estás convirtiendo el resultado de PI a un entero:

```
var question4 = prompt("Cuanto vale PI");
var userAnswer4 = parseInt(question4);
```

Y la solución es muy sencilla. Solo tienes que usar `parseFloat` en vez de `parseInt`:

```
> var question4 = prompt("Cuanto vale PI");
> question4
"3.1416"
> parseInt(question4)
3
> parseFloat(question4)
3.1416
> var userAnswer4 = parseFloat(question4)
> userAnswer4 === 3.14 || userAnswer4 === 3.1416
true
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu pronta y eficaz ayuda, ahora llego a tener solamente 4 respuestas correctas

Comment: @ArturoPérez ya actualicé mi respuesta. Si te sirvió no olvides marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: Muchas gracias ya entendí completamente el por que, te agradezco !